# Fb SSO for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook, timeout, single-sign-on

I am building an iPhone app that uses Facebook login.

I recently changed it to SSO but its asking users to sign again after 8 hours. Is there a way to improve on timeout for Facebook SSO ?

Comment: Your auth token should last far longer than 8 hrs.  Are you actually storing the auth key and expiration in the default user prefs properly?  I assume the user is not running for 8 hours non-stop.  When they restart the app, what is the expiration showing?    

Presumably you're doing this:

`facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kFBAccessToken];
 facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFBExpirationDate];
`

Where kFBExpirationDate = @"FBExpirationDate" or so.

Answer (score 0):

Request permission for offline access.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, [offline_access is being deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/), you can now implement a 'sliding expiry' using the latest SDK - so the more a user uses your app, the less often they will need to log in. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token